# Is it possible to take svn copy exclude particular directory?

Tags: svn, svnignore

I need to take a backup of working copy. If I take svn copy it will copy the entire working copy. I don't want to take the entire project copy. Because one of the directory size is too big. I can manage without taking that directory backup.

**So how do I take svn copy exclude one directory?**

I have two environment called dev and qa. Whenever I am giving build I just take a backup. Usually, I will do the following procedure to take a back up.

1. Right click from the working copy directory, and choose **repo-browser**
2. svn window will open
3. Right click from dev trunk directory and as I shown in the below image
   [copy to tags directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKynX.png)
4. When I am using **copy to** option, I don not want to copy the **Media** directory. And except media directory I would copy all files and folders to **tags** directory.

So except media directory I would like to copy the rest of the files and folders.

If there is any alternative or easy solution to take a backup except particular directory, please let me know.

Comment: The question is phrased in a confusing way. Do you wish to create a branch from the current HEAD node of your working copy? If so, I recommend you do an `svn copy` operation on the server side, and then use `svn del` to remove the directory you are not interested in. You can then checkout a new working copy.

Comment: Okay, "taking a backup of a working copy" is a poor way to describe what you are doing. In Subversion terminology, you are effectively creating a tag, using a server-side operation. You are performing an `svn copy` on the server, and an svn copy takes very little space since it just creates a link in the Subversion database. I suggest you continue to do an `svn copy`, followed by `svn del` on the directory which you aren't interested in. Copy followed by delete will not take up any additional space in the Subversion repository.

Answer (score 1):

```
svn propset svn:ignore dirname .
```

example of directory

```
\project
    \src
    \cache
    \othr
```

now set the property by

```
svn propset svn:ignore cache .
```

Explanation in brief: svn:ignore is the name of the property being set, cache is the value of the property, and . is the directory you're setting this property on. This should be the parent directory of  cache.

To check again

```
> svn proplist
Properties on '.':
  svn:ignore
```

To se ignore's value

```
> svn propget svn:ignore
cache
```

to delete this

```
svn propdel svn:ignore
```

Comment: How do I use this command for copying? I tried in different cases, it was giving me svn error.

Comment: I'm unsure about the exact nature of this question, but I'm sure the answer is not `svn propset`.